# How to differentiate between parse exception and invalid date range

Tags: java

I have this simple program I've written

```
try{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    //Date date = sdf.parse("1/14/1999"); Apologies for confusion
    Date date = sdf.parse(request.getParameter("selectedDate"));
}catch(ParseException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

From what I understand a ParseException will be thrown if the date is out of range or the format given is wrong. I want to be able to tell them apart. How can I can achieve this ?

Edit: When I said out of range I meant something like this 15/15/1999. That's why `setLenient(false)`

Comment: What does "out of range" mean?

Comment: @Andy I don't see any reference to `ParseException` in the doc, for the methods you use. It says `SimpleDateFormat` constructor throws `NullPointerException` and `InvalidArgumentException`, and the `parse` method throws `NullPointerException` (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse).

Comment: @rixo - You're confusing the `parse(String, ParsePosition)` method with the `parse(String)` method, [which is inherited from `DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ParseException` doesn't offer a reliably way of determining the cause of the exception itself. You could invoke `parse` twice setting `lenient` to `true` and `false` and checking its state in the exception block

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
try {
    sdf.setLenient(true);
    Date date = sdf.parse("1/33/1999");
    System.out.println("DateFormat is OK");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    date = sdf.parse("1/33/1999");

} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    if (!sdf.isLenient())  {
        System.out.println("Invalid date");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid date pattern");
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably using `IllegalArgumentException`. Was there a problem with that approach?

Comment: @Reimus No problems. Just hard to imagine that there isn't a class that deals with this.

Answer (score 1):

> format given is wrong.

By that if you mean that the format is invalid, then that throws IllegalArgumentException, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String%29).

**But you should not have to check that**, the pattern you supply is determined at compile time and you should be able to ensure that it is valid; the check should be required only if the pattern is not known at compile time.

Comment: I think they mean if the `sdf.parse("1/14/1999");` doesn't conform to the desired pattern - hence why they `setLenient(false)`.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly have a look at these Methods .I am not good at exceptions but maybe it gives you some help.

```
 try{
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
  sdf.setLenient(false);
  Date date = sdf.parse("1/14/1999");
}catch(ParseException ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(ex.toString());//get cause and message ,localized details
        System.out.println(ex.etErrorOffset()); //get position of error
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I read the doc and see that different exceptions are thrown in the two cases, so you can differentiate based on the exception class:

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    Date date = sdf.parse("1/14/1999");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    // format exception
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    // parse exception
}
```